# PDO non locking query: possible?

Tags: php, mysql, asynchronous, pdo

I am currently requesting a MySQL database to compute some counts and sums with PDO. This process may take a while and the user may remain stuck in front of his browser if he suddenly wants to browse to another page.

I'm trying to figure out if it would be possible to start a MySQL query with PDO, enter a loop until either the query results are available or the user left the page (`connection_aborted()`), finally send the results if the user is still connected else abort the MySQL query. It would be something like this:

```
<?php

$objPDOStatement = $objPDO->prepare("
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM   my_huge_table
    WHERE  <<complex_condition>>
");

$objPDOStatement->execute($arrParameters);

while (
     (connection_aborted() == 0) 
  && (! $objPDOStatement->resultsAvailable()
) {
    usleep(10000);
}

if (connection_aborted() == 0) {
    echo "RESULTS";
} else {
    $objPDOStatement->cancel();
}
```

Is this possible? If so, how? I would like to do this in order the user not to have to wait for the web server (php) to finish the current script/page, ie. not to wait for MySQL to return results if these are finally not used, before serving the next requested script/page.

Thanks.

Comment: You could do this in a few different ways. Ie using web sockets to connect to the server and let it wait for the result, or on request add it to a task queue  and run it with a task runner, then just have the browser poll to see if the results are ready, etc

Comment: You could also use a Queue server like RabitMQ, ActiveMQ, Amazon Simple Queue Service (if your app is hosted on Amazon AWS), MQTT, and so on.
You send the request in the queue, then a worker takes over the task, but your app is independent from the execution of the Worker. Depending on the Queue System you are using, you can also ask from time to time if the Worker finished the execution and when the Worker is finished, collect the result.

Comment: @JimL, the issue is not client side but server side: PHP won't handle any new request for a given client while another one is currently running. Here, even if Ajax calls are used and may be aborted, the PHP script with the SQL statement keeps running until the dataset is returned by PDO.

Comment: @Dragos: nice idea but, unfortunately, it's not possible for me to use these technologies. I'm not allowed to use them in this project.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous queries are only available in mysqli, but not in PDO.

However, what you what is usually achieved simply by means of AJAX call.

Comment: That's not the issue. The request *is* already processed by an Ajax call. However, even if the Ajax call is aborted, the PHP script keeps running as long as PDO did not end its current job. Thus, Apache waits for PHP to end its current process in order to handle the next request in queue. That's why I would like to do that way: to be able to check if the the user is still connected and end immediately the current process if not to free the lock on Apache queue.